# How to get a gravity effect in a CSS animation?

Tags: css, physics

I want to animate an element as if you're looking down at the Earth. The element jumps towards you, hits its apex, and falls back down a little. A side view of the trajectory would be like this:

```
     _
   /   \
  /     |
 |
 |
```

I wasn't able to attain a realistic effect with keyframe animations. Mine looks artificial like this:

```
    /\
   /  \
  /
 /
/
```

**CSS**

```
@keyframes springIn {
    0% {
        transform: scale(0.0);
    }
    80% {
        transform: scale(1.2);
    }
    100% {
        transform: scale(1.0);
    }
}

.someElement {
    animation: springIn 1s linear 1s 1 forwards;
}
```

How do you put parabolic function on the animation to get the gravity effect? I thought I could use [Bezier Curves](http://css3beziercurve.net/), but the CSS standard does not allow points outside of [0, 0].

Comment: This may be a mild improvement using the animation function: http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/jyscZ/ (only done for Chrome)

Comment: @ExplosionPills : Doesn't your `ease-out` apply to the entire animation? I want it to ease-out to the apex and then ease-in falling down from the apex.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think that you can do it using bezier curves.

in you case, it could be something like that:

```
-webkit-transition: all 500ms cubic-bezier(0.310, 0.440, 0.445, 1.650); 
-moz-transition: all 500ms cubic-bezier(0.310, 0.440, 0.445, 1.650); 
-ms-transition: all 500ms cubic-bezier(0.310, 0.440, 0.445, 1.650); 
-o-transition: all 500ms cubic-bezier(0.310, 0.440, 0.445, 1.650); 
transition: all 500ms cubic-bezier(0.310, 0.440, 0.445, 1.650); /* custom */

-webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.310, 0.440, 0.445, 1.650); 
-moz-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.310, 0.440, 0.445, 1.650); 
-ms-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.310, 0.440, 0.445, 1.650); 
-o-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.310, 0.440, 0.445, 1.650); 
transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.310, 0.440, 0.445, 1.650); /* custom */
```

I haven't done it by myself, check this link:

### [css easing animation tool](http://matthewlein.com/ceaser/)

I have made [an example in a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yq9jpgzx/).

I put an outer div to make the hover stable:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="moving"></div>
</div>
```

and the CSS is as follows:

```
.moving {
    position: absolute; width: 200px; height: 150px; top: 50px;  left: 50px;
    background-color: green;
    -webkit-transition: all 5s cubic-bezier(0.310, 0.440, 0.445, 1.650); 
}

.container:hover .moving {
    zoom: 1.5;
}
```

**Editing**

Just an image of what can you get with a bezier curve (from the ease animation tool page) to show that the object speed doesn't need to be constant (and can be almost parabolic)

[image: bezier curve]

Comment: the main problem with this i think is that the object moves at a constant speed, which might throw the realism off a bit.

Comment: @JustinL. Not really, I have added an image to show what you can get

Comment: ah okay, my mistake; i didn't see that the timing function was a bezier curve, not the position.

Comment: In Google Chrome 25 (the most recent version for Windows), Bezier points get clipped between [0.0, 1.0]. The most recent Firefox does not clip, but I've noticed that sometimes the animation works and sometimes it just doesn't animate at all. I believe Bezier curves are still very buggy.

Comment: @JoJo Yes, support is very weak. I just put that info because the OP talked about that, and I hope that the support will grow. Chrome 25.0.1364.172 m clips Bezier transitions for some properties. The zoom property (see fiddle that I provided) works ok. (or at least it seems like that to me). BYW, I didn't say that in the fiddle the transition is triggered hovering the div.

Comment: The hyper bezier curve works on iOS 6, which is the only platform I need it to work on.

Comment: The curve above isn't really a parabola; it won't look "quite right".  You can use cubic beziers to generate ACTUAL parabolic trajectories - see my solution below.  For a complete parabolic jump-and-fall-all-the-way-back, or if the browser is clipping to [0,1], then you just need to use 2 keyframes, half a parabola each.

Comment: Amazing! I can feel my div jumping up and down.

But I wouldn't recommend this for a parabolic effect. Great for jumping animations!

Answer (score 10):

Use `animation-timing-function` **in your keyframes** to make the two transitions (rise followed by fall) parabolic.

---

To do this correctly (i.e. according to physics), you need firstly make sure that the 'peak' point scale and time correspond properly.  Your animation runs from 0% to 100%, and the top of the parabola (point of maximum scale) is somewhere between the two, let's call it *m*%.  The scale starts at 0 (at 0%), ends at 1 (at 100%) and peaks at let's say *s* (at *m*%).  Then using a bit of basic math, the relationship between these two variables is:

```
m = 100 / (1 + sqrt(s-1))
```

or

```
s = (100/m - 1)^2 + 1
```

...so for the peak to be reached at 80%, you need *s* = 17/16 = 1.0625

alternatively, for a max scale *s* of 1.2, you need to peak at *m* = 69.0983... %

---

Now, to make the transitions properly parabolic, you need to use parabolic `animation-timing-function` settings.  You want to effectively use something *like* `ease-out` as your object shoots up, and *like* `ease-in` as it starts falling back down... but the cubic bezier curves associated with these two keywords are not exactly parabolas.

Instead, use:

```
animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.33333, 0.66667, 0.66667, 1)
```

for the "rise" part of the animation, and:

```
animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.33333, 0, 0.66667, 0.33333)
```

for the "fall" part.  These *do* give you exact parabolas. (See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/335226/convert-segment-of-parabola-to-quadratic-bezier-curve) for the maths behind the derivation of these values; note that ideally you'd use 1/3 rather than 0.33333 and 2/3 rather than 0.66667, but CSS doesn't allow fractions).

Putting all this together gives you this CSS:

```
.someElement { animation: springIn 1s linear 1s 1 none }

@keyframes springIn
{
  0% { transform: scale(0.0); animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.33333, 0.66667, 0.66667, 1) }
  69.0983% { transform: scale(1.2); animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.33333, 0, 0.66667, 0.33333) }
  100% { transform: scale(1.0) }
}
```

...and if I've done my sums right, that should give you a perfectly parabolic animation trajectory!

(Note: I changed the animation-fill-mode to "none" because it did not seem necessary for the animation to continue enforcing `transform: scale(1.0)` after it ends.  If this is actually necessary for some reason, change this value back to "forwards").

Comment: Jon z, you're scaling is off because the DIV is full-page-width, but only the left-aligned text in it is visible.  Also, your opacity fades back to zero at the peak point, so you never see the "descent" part.  I think this is more like what the OP had in mind:  http://jsfiddle.net/6La14v1c/4/

Answer (score 1):

Adobe has provided a nice [example](http://www.adobe.com/inspire/2013/04/animating-interactive-experiences-css.html) which only uses standard ease-in/ease-out timing functions. Even though it might not be completely "physical" (i e, not parabolic), it might still be good enough for many situations. There is a demo on the page if you scroll down to the section **Physics is your friend**.

```
div {
    width:140px;
    height:140px;
    border-radius: 70px;
    background:red;
    position:relative;
    animation: jump 1s infinite;
}

@keyframes jump {
    0% {top: 0;animation-timing-function: ease-in;}
    50% {top: 140px;height: 140px;animation-timing-function: ease-out;}
    55% {top: 160px; height: 120px;border-radius: 70px / 60px;animation-timing-function: ease-in;}
    65% {top: 120px; height: 140px;border-radius: 70px;animation-timing-function: ease-out;}
    95% {top: 0;animation-timing-function: ease-in;}
    100% {top: 0;animation-timing-function: ease-in;}
}
```

Source: http://www.adobe.com/inspire/2013/04/animating-interactive-experiences-css.html